# How to restore terminal tool windows on startup

Tags: phpstorm

Using phpStorm 9.0, i often end-up having to invalidate caches and restart (because REST api performance degrades over time).  Is there a way/configuration i did not see to restore my terminal window tools upon restart (the tool itself, window title, and hopefully the working directory)

[image: as shown here]

tia

Comment: Trick Tip: Use ctrl+tab to show a pop-up menu or you can press ALT+F12.

Comment: @ThiagoAugustusOliveira yes, thank you for that information. My issue is that after a restart, my terminal windows have vanished and i have to 'recreate' them by hand before being 'good to go code'.

Comment: I understand you, you are looking for some 'terminal path cache', I don't know if phpstorm has it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment such functionality does not exist.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-117946 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on progress.

---

**P.S.** You may also be interested in these related tickets:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-118868
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-134884

Comment: thanks, upvoted them all ... not holding my breath though.